# Is there a Mongodb aggregation pipeline current status or monitoring?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm doing analisis of a mongodb database using the aggregation framework.
I'm trying to optimize what I do, but sometimes some of the operations just take too much.

When I cancel a job I have the terrible sensation that it was about to end. Is there any way to track the progress of the pipeline?

Any idea or hack is welcome.

Comment: I haven't actually checked if they come under `currentOp()`, why not give it a try?